# Increment of Id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

The id will increment by 1, such as 00001. But whenever I insert new data, the increment will restart. i want it to continue from the last increment.

**Query**

```
string GetMaxIdSql =
@"select isnull(Max(convert(int, ApplicationId)),0) as ApplicationId, isnull(Max(convert(int, Id)),0) as Id from Application where isnumeric(id) = 1 and isnumeric(applicationid) = 1";
```

**Command**

```
resultMaxId.Id = (Convert.ToInt32(resultMaxId.Id) + 1).ToString();         
string id = string.Format("{0}", resultMaxId.Id.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'));
```

Comment: It's probably silly to ask, but are you sure your `ApplicationId` and `Id` columns in the database table are `int` type and not `varchar`, or they do not have un-convertable values (strings which you can't convert to int).

Comment: it may be because those columns are alphanumeric and trying to convert them to `int` results in error.

Comment: If you have junk data in your table (where IDs or ApplicationIDs can't be converted because they contain letters or other characters that aren't numbers), then it's going to throw an error. You could change the query to include `where isnumeric(id) = 1 and isnumeric(applicationid) = 1`, but realistically you should fix your data.

Comment: Swap your ISNULL and MAX in your SQL statement. It won't fix your error but is likely what you really want. IF you are on SQL 2016 use TRY_CONVERT to prevent your error. To find your rogue value you can start with ISNUMERIC but understand it returns anything that could be a numeric type including stuff like scientific notation 1e4, etc....

Comment: Both ApplicationId and Id are varchar, i'm trying to convert them to int. I tried to change it to varchar in the sql code and it has the error incorrect string format. So i don't think that's the solution.

Comment: When i swap it ISNULL and MAX. it has the error "The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)."

Comment: I meant the logic of your max and is null not just the words.

Comment: You haven't posted the most important part of the error. the error should be something like `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'gh555' to data type int.`. In this case `gh555` is just dirty data. besides your null check does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please check complete data in ApplicationId and Id columns. It may be having some chars which is causing this issue.